# Why java function does not work in android studio but can work in intellij idea using kotlin language and gradle script

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

I am using Microsoft operating system. Below are my code.
This one is written in android studio. Here I use `${project_name}\app\src\main\res` as the
`resources root` directory. I use the same package for the two classes declared below.

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths

class Parser(fileName:String){
     val fileName=fileName
     val fileContent=getContent()

fun getContent():String{
    val encoded= Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(".",fileName))
    //here relative path is the `res` folder in android studio 
    return String(encoded, Charset.defaultCharset())
    }
}

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val parser=Parser("default.vert")
    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_test).also {
        it.text=parser.fileContent
        }
    }
}
```

it says:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: ./default.vert`

But in intellij idea community edition:

Basically the same code is used but with slightly different file path, because I mark one of
the folders to become the default `resources root` directory:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths

class Parser(fileName:String){
    val fileName=fileName
    val fileContent=getContent()
    fun getContent():String{
        val encoded= 
        Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(".","src","main","resources",fileName))
        //here I used the most top level directory (maybe the scientific term is `root` 
        //but I am not sure)in the project which was named `Test`.
        return String(encoded, Charset.defaultCharset())
        }
    }

fun main(){
    val parser=Parser("test.vert")
    print(parser.fileContent)
}
```

and it prints the content:

```
layout (location=0) in vec4 vPosition;

void main(){
    gl_Position=vPosition;
}
```

**How can I make the code run in Android studio too ? using kotlin**

I have tried absolute path as well such as:
`c:\\users\\${user_name}\\..until_the_file\\default.vert`
but still got `exception` fileNotFoundException from android studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android handles files differently from a desktop JVM app. You must package the files in either your resources (`\app\src\main\res\raw`) or assets (`\app\src\main\assets`), and then retrieve them either through `resources.openRawResource()` or `assets.open()` respectively. You will not be using direct file paths. Your local directories are not part of the packaged app installed on the device or emulator. You can only get InputStreams.

Documentation: [Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) and [Assets](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager)

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.content.Context

class Program(val context: Context, val id:Int){
    val fileContent=getContent()

    private fun getContent(): String {
        try {
            val input = context.resources.openRawResource(id)
            val size=input.available()
            val buffer=ByteArray(size)
            input.read(buffer)
            input.close()
            return String(buffer,Charsets.UTF_8)
        }
        catch(e:Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
            return ""
        } 
    }
}
```

Thanks to this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-read-a-text-file-in-android/ it taught me how to use `InputStream` to read a file.

I thought I will need to cast `InputStream` to `FileInputStream` because it is abstract class. In C++, we never can use abstract class unless we inherit from that abstact class an overriding the appropriate function.

But this time in java/kotlin, we can do it straight away.